# Magento 2 - change user in Ubuntu

Tags: magento2, reindex, permissions, exception

My previous directory is this

```
pratyush@pratyush-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$
```

but when I run  `sudo -i` for removing xampp then it's showing this

```
root@pratyush-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~#
```

How can I move again the previous command?

Comment: well...it's pretty obvious...you don't have access to the db? Do you have a docker container or vagrant box (or anything else similar) where you have set up your project?

Comment: Marius@ on local host

Comment: maybe your user have limited access

Comment: Marius@ i m setup my all data on local machine on lamp, and i have create databse with root user and no password .

Comment: kunj@ how is possible on localhost

Comment: go in phpMyAdmin and edit your user check `Privileges`. `All privileges` is selected? also try to create new table with that user.

Comment: kung @ site run one time with all configuration after this ,current error is coming

Comment: kung @module:status commond run one time

Comment: Login into terminal using root user of phpmyadmin.

Comment: Dhaduk Mitesh@how can i login in trminal

Comment: `ssh user_name@your_IP`  Ex.: ssh root@127.0.0.1

Comment: ssh root@127.0.0.1 this will be work on magento 2

Comment: Dhaduk Mitesh@let me know if any remaining  solution. let me know how can i check appche port

Comment: Replace `127.0.0.1` with your server IP. and try to login in a terminal.

Comment: dhaduk@ after run this common sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
 I am getting this issue .I do not why but this is too dificult

Comment: here is my db connection file,@@'db' => [
    'table_prefix' => 'astro',
    'connection' => [
      'default' => [
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'dbname' => 'astrokapoor_new',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'active' => '1'
      ]
    ]
  ],

Comment: Execute this in  MySQL: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON astrokapoor_new . * TO 'root'@'localhost';`